# Does MacOS locally store information about external drives?

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, metadata

I used a borrowed Mac to transfer sensitive data directly between two USB thumb drives. Ideally, I'd like to not leave a single trace of the files and transfers on the borrowed Mac, but I understand that a modern OS might store a lot of tiny bits of information anywhere and everywhere. What are these on MacOS? (In my case, specifically, MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra)

I noticed that I couldn't safely eject the drives because Spotlight were indexing them for a pretty long time. But as far as I have understood, these indexes are only placed on the external drives themselves, and not anywhere on the Mac. Is this assumption correct?

In short:

- which processes might locally store information of externally mounted drives,
- what kind of information are they storing, and
- how can I "clean up" before giving the Mac back to its owner?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448760/does-macos-store-information-locally-about-external-drives

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for the advice, and I apologize for breaking etiquette. To explain: this was posted on the Apple stackexchange last week, but despite a few upvotes, no one answered. I'm not very familiar with the spaces, but I thought maybe those who know the answer might be more available here on Superuser than on the regular Apple site. Therefore I waited a week without answer before trying my luck here. I tried to flag it for migration now, but it seems I could only migrate it to apple.meta.stackexchange...?

Comment: In principle yes, Spotlight is storing the index on the drive itself. But you can prevent Spotlight from indexing it at all by creating an empty file `.metadata_never_index` at the root of the drive. Now, I'm afraid that it's impossible to make sure that absolutely nothing will be left behind in the OS after you remove the drive...